# How to Remove GIT version control from XCode 5 Project

Tags: ios, xcode, git

Can anyone tell me how to completely remove GIT version control from an XCode 5 project?

I decided to start using git when I upgraded to XCode 5, but then ran into the problem with excluding .xcuserstate in the .gitignore file.  It would be successful, then the "User Interface State" message would come up while trying to commit everything else, and I couldn't get rid of it.  There are lots of suggestions in here for terminal commands etc., but in the end I would get into a viscious circle.

Having to go out of the IDE to run several terminal commands does not seem to me to be a well-integrated versioning system.

I'm the only one working on this project so simply backing everything up on a regular basis is going to have to do.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try my solution below?

Comment: Downvoting: why do you think that Git won't worknfor your project? Learn to use it rather than ripping it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Xcode 5

- Go To Xcode -- > Preference
- Select "Source Control"
- Deselect "Enable Source Control"

Xcode 5 removed the Repositories Organizer

Comment: I have a question: Does this disable source control for a single project or for all xCode projects?

Comment: I used this but the directory still had the hidden .git directory intact. An therefore maybe was still operating. You can see this folder via terminal with ls -a  command. I removed the .git directory, which is the git directory via rm -rf .git  This removed (deleted) the git directory and therefore removed git version control.